# PHP MYSQL Form Submit Multiple Times

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to have my form submit several rows one for each number in the number field.

[image: HTML Form]

In the number field, I want to enter several number separated by commas (e.g. 10,8,95,109), then a single comment (e.g. Hello). When submitted, that should insert one row per number into the db.

So in the database, this would be what is submitted.

| Number | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Hello |
| 8 | Hello |
| 95 | Hello |
| 109 | Hello |

I would also like this to only accept number (and commas etc).

Thanks

Comment: You can separate values with `explode()` function. is that a solution for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. The actual implementation depends on your actual setup and your DB implementation.

```
<?php
$numb_str = "10,8,95,109";
$comment = "Hello";

$numb_arr = explode(',', $numb_str);

$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table (numb, comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $numb, $comment);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($numb_arr); $i++) {
    $numb = $numb_arr[$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$inputNumbers = "10,8,95,109";
$comment = "Hello";
$inputNumbers = explode(",",$inputNumbers);
    
foreach($inputNumbers as $inputNumber){
//use db query to insert for each inputNumber
//"INSERT INTO <tableName> (Number, Comment)
//VALUES ( $inputNumber, $comment)"
}
```